# Not able to use python eval() in pyspark as pandas udf but the same in python udf works

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, user-defined-functions

I am a newbie to pandas udf in pyspark and need help in applying a udf for every row in a large dataframe (>100 million rows)
I have a column in my dataframe that contains multiple conditions that use the columns within the dataframe. The best way to apply the conditions on each row is to use the python eval. python eval when used in a python udf works fine but takes forever to run as I have a few million rows. The same when tried in Pandas udf fails to run, throws a Python exception "PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: eval() arg 1 must be a string, bytes or code object'"

Sample code as below,
This code does not work,

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import pandas_udf, PandasUDFType
import pandas as pd
@pandas_udf('boolean', PandasUDFType.SCALAR)
def pandas_eval(A: str, B: str, logic:str) -> bool:
  return eval(logic)

a=spark.createDataFrame([("val", "val2","A!='val1' and B=='val2'")], ['A', 'B','logic'])
a.show()
a.withColumn('Result', pandas_eval(a.A,a.B,a.logic)).show()
```

This works but is not scalable,

```
#Plain UDF works with the same syntax
a=spark.createDataFrame([("val", "val2","A!='val1' and B=='val2'")], ['A', 'B','logic'])

def comp_eval(A,B,logic):
  return eval(logic)
spark.udf.register("comp_eval", comp_eval)
comp_eval = udf(comp_eval, T.StringType())

#Apply UDF
a = a.withColumn("comp_eval_result",comp_eval(a.A,a.B,a.logic))
display(a)
```

Can anyone suggest what I am doing wrong or an alternate way to evaluate the conditions.

Comment: " I have a column in my dataframe that contains multiple conditions that use the columns within the dataframe. The best way to apply the conditions on each row is to use the python eval" Just so you know, this is *a very bad way to design whatever it is you are trying to accomplish*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I agree with you but the underlying business is to classify each row of the data frame based on the values contained within it. I cannot use CASE WHEN THEN as there could be multiple classifiers that are applicable to one row.

Answer (score 0):

Your python udf receives 1 row of "logic" column as string object.

Pandas udf sends 1000(default) rows of "logic" column as pandas.series object,
which is why eval(logic) throws an error saying not a string object

Try

```
return logic.apply(eval)
```

instead of

```
return eval(logic)
```